# MySQL quote escaped still returns error

Tags: mysql, escaping, quote

```
SELECT * FROM `entries` WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('Linux\'s')
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's'' at line 1

I don't have the vaguest idea why this error persists when the quote is escaped.

PS: The upper query works in **phpMyAdmin**.

```
class SmalllightSearch extends Smalllight {

        //----- SEARCH BY FIELD VALUE -----\\
        public function searchByFieldValue($field, $value, $smart = true, $limit = NULL, array $orderby = NULL) {
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $entries = array();
            $q = "SELECT * FROM `".$this->table."` WHERE MATCH (`$field`) AGAINST ('$value')";
            echo $q;

            if($orderby != NULL) {
                $list = array();
                foreach($orderby as $k => $v) { array_push($list, '`'.$k.'` '.$v); }
                $order = implode(', ', $list);
                $q .= ' ORDER BY '.$order;
            }
            if($limit != NULL) { $q .= ' LIMIT '.$limit; }

            $r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                array_push($entries, $row);
            }

            if($smart == true) {
                $right = new Smalllight('right');
                $wrong = new Smalllight('wrong');
                $words = str_word_count($value, 1);

                foreach($words as $word_key => $word_value) {
                    $find_right = $right->findByFieldValue('value', $word_value);

                    if($find_right == false) {
                        $find_wrong = $wrong->findByFieldValue('value', $word_value);

                        if($find_wrong == true) {
                            $pair_right = $right->findById($find_wrong[0]['right_id']);
                            $words[$word_key] = $pair_right['value'];
                        }
                        else {
                            $pattern_right = $right->findByPattern('value', $word_value, 5, array('occur' => 'DESC'));

                            if($pattern_right == true) {
                                foreach($pattern_right as $pattern_key => $pattern) {
                                    similar_text($word_value, $pattern['value'], $similar);

                                    if($similar >= 70 && $word_value !== $pattern['value']) {
                                        $wrong->setValue('right_id', $pattern['id']);
                                        $wrong->setValue('value', $word_value);
                                        $wrong->store();
                                        $words[$word_key] = $pattern['value'];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $meaning = implode(' ', $words);
                if($meaning != $value) {
                    $link = implode('+', $words);
                    echo 'Did you mean: <a href="index.php?search='.$link.'">'.$meaning.'</a><br/>';
                }
                return $entries;
            }

            elseif($smart == false) {
                return $entries;
            }
        }
}
```

This is how I execute it:

```
if($_GET['search']) {
        $slight = new SmalllightSearch('entries');
        $entries = $slight->searchByFieldValue('title', $_GET['search']);
        if($entries == true) {
            foreach($entries as $entry) {
                echo '<b>'.$entry['title'].'</b><br/>'.$entry['body'].'<br/><br/>';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo '<br/>No results found for: <b>'.$_GET['search'].'</b>';
        }
    }
```

There is no need to echo right before, because the limit and orderby parameters are not set.

Comment: "The upper query works in phpMyAdmin." --- and where it doesn't work?

Comment: try ``SELECT * FROM `entries` WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('Linux''s')``, i.e. use another `'` to escape.

Comment: It doesn't work in my PHP script.

Comment: Now `echo` the final query version, not intermediate results.

Comment: I did it and same result, tho it wasn't needed because I haven't set the limit and order parameters in the function.

Comment: @Alexandrw: I don't believe it then.

Comment: Tell me how I can chat you some teamviewer data and you will test and see for yourself. I'm going to pull out all my hair in the next hours...

Answer (score 2):

It obviously doesn't work in php because `\'` is treated as an escape sequence, thus it's parsed by php.

So you need to escape a slash as well

```
AGAINST('Linux\\\'s')
```

PS: if you used prepared statements or at least properly used escape functions your mysql client provides - it wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the PHP code (part of it):

```
public function searchByFieldValue($field, $value, $smart = true, $limit = NULL, array $orderby = NULL) {
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $entries = array();
            $q = "SELECT * FROM `".$this->table."` WHERE MATCH (`$field`) AGAINST ('$value')";
            echo $q;
```

And this is the output:

SELECT * FROM `entries` WHERE MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ('Linux\'s')You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's'' at line 1

Comment: In my database, Linux's is written as Linux's, not Linux\'s

Comment: This code doesn't run the generated query thus it cannot cause the given error. PS: Put that in the question

Comment: I really don't know what to do... :(

Comment: it's not helpful. Your code doesn't execute the query, so it cannot cause the given error.

Comment: i execute the function like this: 
`$slight = new SmalllightSearch('entries');
$entries = $slight->searchByFieldValue('title', $_GET['search']);`
And inside the GET search i type Linux's... is this helpful now?

Comment: you're executing the function like that. But how do you run the query? I don't see any `mysql_query` in the code or whatever

Comment: `$r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
array_push($entries, $row);
}`

Comment: It's not possible for this code to throw such an error.

Comment: It does it sadly :( i could show you over teamviewer the entire code... this is why i'm telling you that the generated query by this code actually works in phpMyAdmin, but not here :( and I don't know what to do.

Comment: put the whole function to the question.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved, I needed to add '\' in the str_word_count() function so it would recognise \ as part of a word.

```
$words = str_word_count($value, 1, '\\');
```